# Wordpress Footer Missing After Website Hack

Tags: footer, hacked

My wordpress website has been hacked, once recovered i can't seem to view the footer. I have checked the theme options / widgets and the settings seems fine.

Kindly advise on possible causes and solutions.

website address: www.boltonuniform.co.za

Comment: Thanks for the informative response toscho - much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Getting hacked with WordPress is not a great thing to experience. Did you take a look at the [Hardening WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) codex page?

Most of the time you get extra PHP code in some of your WordPress Core, Theme and plugin files. I guess this happened to you too and tried to remove this. Could it be possible you removed too much? Try 'reinstalling' your theme from a newly downloaded zip file. Just replace your current directory.

I've one of my client's sites get hacked I usually do:

1. Transfer the site to a local development environment.
2. Reinstalling a fresh copy of WordPress
3. Reinstalling fresh copies of plugins.
4. Reinstalling fresh copies of Theme.
5. Manually check and copy all content of posts, pages etc.

I do this because you can never be certain you missed a bit of the hack!